# Cómo redireccionar de HTTPS a toda las páginas excepto una?

Tags: ssl

Tengo un certificado SSL y puse el Rewrite de Cloudflare pero no en todas las unas páginas funcionan. Como puedo forzar todas las página al https, excepto una.

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices. :-)  Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega más información como a qué te refieres con que el formulario falla y, de ser posible, incluye el código de ese formulario.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta

Comment: ¡Quedó peor! Olvidaste mencionar porqué no funciona el formulario y agregar el código.

Comment: Lo del formulario no importa, cuando no uso ssl el formulario funciona correctamente

Comment: ¡Ah, bueno, si no importa, entonces no sé qué hacemos aquí!

Comment: puedes visitar el sitio web. https://fowmovies.ml, ves que en algunas paginas no funciona el ssl

Comment: Si tienes SSL porque forzar a que todas tengan seguridad excepto una?, que sentido tiene?, porque querrias hacerlo??

Answer (score 0):

Espero que no hayas estado dos años esperando esta respuesta, pero lo importante es:

Dado que tienes activada la nubecita naranja en un subdominio, y usas el universal SSL de cloudflare, tienes tres modalidades:

1. Flexible (a.k.a. de mentiritas) tu servidor en realidad recibe http en el puerto 80
2. Strict, tu servidor recibe https en el puerto 443, cualquier certificado que presente a la petición se considera válido
3. Full: tu servidor recibe https en el puerto 443, cloudflare comprueba si le respondes con un SSL válido.

Dejemos el 3 de lado. Cuando habilitas cloudflare y sigues las recomendaciones de seguridad, puede que algunas URL que hoy funcionan dejen de funcionar (ej porque comparan la petición en el front, que es https, con el request que reciben, que es http, o porque están presentando un certificado de verdad en el 443 pero cloudflare insiste en pedirlo al 443). Si eso pasa con todas tus URLs y subdominios, puede que estés configurando mal el servicio. Si para con un solo subdominio, siempre puedes apagar la nubecita para él.

**Peero** (aquí llegamos a lo medular) si quieres ajustar en detalle el comportamiento de un subdominio o de toda la zona sujeto a un patrón de URL, revisa Page Rules. Te permitirán ajustar granularmente los settings acorde a un patrón, subdirectorio o similar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]